# How to do greater than X and less than Y in VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Here is what I have tried... which is completely wrong I assume, as it did not work.

```
If ProgressBar1.Value > 5 < 20 Then
    Label8.Text = "Hello"
End If
```

All help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
If ProgressBar1.Value > 5 AndAlso ProgressBar1.Value < 20 Then
    Label8.Text = "Hello"
End If
```

Is one way.

`AndAlso` means that the condition will 'short circuit' if the first value evaluates to false.  So if ProgressBar1.Value is not > 5 - it won't bother checking the rest of the condition.

You could also write it using `And`

```
If ProgressBar1.Value > 5 And ProgressBar1.Value < 20 Then
    Label8.Text = "Hello"
End If
```

and it would evaluate both conditions.  In this particular case, it won't make much difference, but I generally prefer AndAlso/OrElse over And/Or

Answer (score 2):

You have to do an and statement using the "And" line. It should look something like this

```
If ProgressBar1.Value > 5 And ProgressBar1.Value < 20 Then
    Label8.Text = "Hello"
End If
```

Additionally you can use the "or" statement if you just want one of them to be true.